# Flink with zookeeper: Service temporarily unavailable due to an ongoing leader election. Please refresh

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to run the flink cluster with High-availability mode. Hence I have made the setting as per [JobManager High Availability](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/setup/jobmanager_high_availability.html) into flink configuration files. When I start the zookeeper quorum by using `start-zookeeper-quorum.sh`, I am able to start two zookeerper servers(peers) on two machines. but when I start the flink cluster with 2 JobManagers, I get the message as `Service temporarily unavailable due to an ongoing leader election. Please refresh.` on web UI of flink.

What does this massage means? Is there a way to notify the leader in configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your zookeeper installation. Your zk nodes can not choose a leader. Also number of two nodes is not the best choice. You should have at least 3 instances or other greater odd number.

You should check the admin docs of Zookeeper for instance [here](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/zookeeperAdmin.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I have run the cluster with 2 zookeepers successfully, only I need to set the `syncLimit=50` in my zoo.cfg file